# Is there a way to reverse dope sheet frames for a reversed animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, performance, dopesheet

so I made this figure and make it dance for around 230 frames.
The problem is that I need more animation time to film longer with the camera, therefore I need more frames.
The animation jumps back to the original position once its done, but that does't make the whole animation fluid looking at all.

So I got the idea to maybe double the amount of frames by copy pasting in the dope sheet, and to make the figure reverse dance back to the origin position in the 1 Frame, without an awkward jump teleportation to the beginning.

To reverse the dance it would kinda require to reverse the copied frames on the dope sheet, so it dances back to the starting point.
Is there a tool that could reverse the selected frame array in the dope sheet?

[image]

*typo in pic: reversed not "reverded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can duplicate all your keyframes, put the playhead at the middle of the selection and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>.

You can also switch your *Dope Sheet* to *Action Editor* mode, push down the action into the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, select the strip, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in order to link-duplicate, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for a simple duplication, open the *N panel > Strip > Active Strip* and click on the *Playback Reversed* option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TO Flip your animation

1. Select the all keys.
2. make sure you are on your starting frame.
3. Make sure your mouse pointer is on the timeline.
4. Then press "S" and then "X" and "-1"
5. This should flip the keys
6. To move the keys to starting position press "G" "X" and "30" (number dependeding on the last frame number)

This should flip your animation